# I created a file to access all the global variables. I am unable to access global variable in the UDFs defined in pyspark-sql queries

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

File with defined global variables:

```
#Globals.py--
def init():
    global XYZ
    XYZ='Some Variable'
    print("GLobal Variables initialized Successfully ")
```

This is the udf function trying to access the 'XYZ' global variable

```
import Globals

#udfs.py
def trans_thrp_cd():
    try:
        global xyz
        print(xyz)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in fetching value from the globals "+ str(e))
```

```
#main.py
import Globals
spark and other modules import-initialization
register functions as pyspark-hive UDFs

df=hive_context.sql("select trans_thrp_cd from test.people")
df.show()
```

Getting the below mentioned error:

```
#Error
module 'Globals' has no attribute 'XYZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Globals.py:

```
global XYZ
XYZ = 'Some variable'
```

In udfs.py:

```
import Globals
print(Globals.XYZ)
```

Comment: Thanks for you input. Since i am using this UDF using **pyspark-sql** i am still facing this issue.